# changing the value of a variable simultaneously on two similar modules

Tags: java, java-threads

I have written a Java module which is supposed to be run on two floodlight controllers. I have a topology in mininet which consists of 2 floodlight controllers (c1 and c2), a switch (s1) which is connected to c1 and 2 hosts (h1 and h2) that are connected to this switch. I'm writing a program in which when c1 receives an ICMP packet from s1, it will send a Hello message to c2.

```
.
.
.

public class Mactracker implements IFloodlightModule, IOFMessageListener {

    protected static IHAControllerService hacontroller;
    protected static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mactracker.class);
    protected IFloodlightProviderService floodlightProvider;
    protected Set<Long> macAddresses;
    private static NetworkNode network;
    private volatile int RFlag = 0;
    private String message;
    private static Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
.
.
.

    @Override
    public void startUp(FloodlightModuleContext context) throws FloodlightModuleException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        floodlightProvider.addOFMessageListener(OFType.PACKET_IN, this);
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor1 = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        ThreadClass ts1 = new ThreadClass ();
        scheduledThreadPoolExecutor1.scheduleAtFixedRate(ts1, 2, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
.
.
.

    @Override
    public net.floodlightcontroller.core.IListener.Command receive(IOFSwitch sw, OFMessage msg,
            FloodlightContext cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Ethernet eth =
                IFloodlightProviderService.bcStore.get(cntx,
                                            IFloodlightProviderService.CONTEXT_PI_PAYLOAD);
        if (eth.getEtherType() == EthType.IPv4) {
            IPv4 ipv4 = (IPv4) eth.getPayload();

            if ( ipv4.getProtocol().equals(IpProtocol.ICMP)){
                logger.warn ("ICMP Packet Received!:-)");
                ICMP icmp = (ICMP) ipv4.getPayload();
                logger.warn ("icmp.getIcmpType: "+icmp.getIcmpType());

                //I will write codes for sending the message
                RFlag = 1;              
            }
        }

        return Command.CONTINUE;
    }

    class ThreadClass implements Runnable {

        ThreadClass(){};
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (RFlag == 1) {
                //I will write codes for receiving the message          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For those who may not be familiar with floodlight or mininet, in this module **receive** is listening for the messages sent from switches (it listens on port 6653 for c1, port 7753 for c2). So in my receive() function, when c1 receives a message from the switch, it will send a message to c2 and will change the value of RFlag to 1.

I also have a thread in my module (ThreadClass) which checks the value of RFlag and if RFlag=1, this thread will implement some tasks on both c1 and c2.

The problem is that since the value of RFlag is changed when c1 receives a message, the tasks which I have defined in the thread is just implemented in c1, not c2 (because c2 has not received the message and the value of RFlag is still 0 for c2).

So my question is: How can I change the value of RFlag to 1 on c2 when this value is changed to 1 on c1? Is it possible?